# How do I use RAPIDS on python if it is not working

Tags: python, anaconda, rapids, cuml

Hi guys I am trying to acces gpu accelerated regression trees through cuml from rapids. However I can't seem to be able to download rapids as instructed> I am trying to dwonload through anaconds prompt in the working directory using the stated code:

**Anaconda prompt**:

```
conda create -n rapids-22.12 -c rapidsai -c conda-forge -c nvidia  \
rapids=22.12 python=3.9 cudatoolkit=11.5
```

Everytime I try it says that the package can not be found , I've recentley tried to download CUDA and have but can't using the standard command to see what cuda version I have. I have a rtx3070 I am on windows 10 and i am attampting to do this through pycharm and the anaconda prompt terminal however it doesn't seem to work also trying to install it though pip does not work either sadly.

So I tried using PIP install ,tried using the previous conda coda and I either get an error or that the packlages can not be found.

Comment: Have you followed the guide at https://rapids.ai/wsl2 . RAPIDS packages do not officially support Windows 10. Are you able to upgrade to Windows 11?

Comment: Thanks, got unlucky with the windows 11 upgrade, I have TPM but have a 3600G so it won't work, thanks for your help though. Saw something about using WSL gonna check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update rapids work if you use something like wsl in windows, a Linux subsystem that can get engrained into windows. You can then install conda and then install rapids through that and this will make a seperate rapids environment that you can use through python and better yet you can use a jupyter notebook with it.